# Swift 3 and Alamofire - Image and data from JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift3, alamofire

I have a project which is trying to bring in data from a web url using alamofire. I am trying to bring in image and text but keep getting build failed. I am trying to add the data (image and text) to tags = 1 and 2. My code is below any help would be appreciated. I am fairly new to Swift. Thanks

**SWIFT**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

struct postinput {
    let mainImage : UIImage!
    let name : String!

}


class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var postsinput = [postinput]()

    var mainURL = "https://www.testJSON.com"

    typealias JSONstandard = [String : AnyObject]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        callAlamo(url: mainURL)
    }

    func callAlamo(url : String){
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
            response in

            self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)


        })

    }

    func parseData(JSONData : Data) {
        do {
            var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONstandard

            if let posts = readableJSON["posts"] as? [JSONstandard] {
                for post in posts { 
                    let title = post["title"] as! String

                    if let images = post["image"] as? JSONstandard {
                        let mainImageURL = URL(string: imageData["url"] as! String)
                        let mainImageData = NSData(contentsOf: mainImageURL!)

                        let mainImage = UIImage(data: mainImageData as! Data)

                    }

                    postsinput.append(postinput.init(mainImage: mainImage, name: name))


                }

                self.tableView.reloadData() 
            }

        }


        catch {
            print(error)
        }


    }




    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postsinput.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        // cell?.textLabel?.text = titles[indexPath.row]

        let mainImageView = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView

        mainImageView.image = postsinput[indexPath.row].mainImage

        let mainLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

        mainLabel.text = postsinput[indexPath.row].name


        return cell!
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

**JSON**

```
 { posts: [ { id: “000000”, url: "/content/interview2”, date: "2016-11-03 09:01:41", modified: "2016-11-03 09:03:47", title: "An interview", image: "https://www.example.com/sites/default/files/oregood.jpeg", summary: { value: "<p>Latin text here</p> ", format: "filtered_html" } ]}
```

Comment: what is `imageData` and `name` in your `parseData` function?

Comment: Where is the build failing?

Comment: inside your `func parseData(JSONData : Data)`

Comment: What is the build failure error you get ?

Comment: I am following a tutorial, so the imageData and name, may not correspond to my JSON structure which is why I am confused.

Comment: The errors are corresponding to the imageData "unresolved identifier, same with 'name'.

Comment: Hi, check my answer once and let me know what happened

Comment: I get this error for the second line above: Cannot convert value of type 'TableViewController.JSONstandard' (aka 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>') to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: Are you sure, the json you gave here is correct?

Comment: I corrected it to: let mainImageURL = URL(string: imageUrl["url"] as! String)

Comment: no errors now but there is no data coming into the app, its all empty

Answer (score 0):

The following are the reasons for your build error are the following:

1. you added this line `postsinput.append(postinput.init(mainImage: mainImage, name: name))`
    outside the context where `mainImage` is obtained. Based on the json, I believe that you are supposed to rewrite it like this.

   ```
   if let imageUrl = post["image"] as? JSONstandard {
      let mainImageURL = URL(string: imageUrl)
      let mainImageData = NSData(contentsOf: mainImageURL!)

      let mainImage = UIImage(data: mainImageData as! Data)
      postsinput.append(postinput.init(mainImage: mainImage, name: title))
   }
   ```
2. Even if you do that, the variables `imageData` and `name` are undefined. You should look into that.
3. Just a suggestion, do not force unwrap optionals. Use optional binding wherever possible.

Comment: Krishna, I am trying to bring in the image from the JSON, I have followed a tutorial which is why the imageData and name are identified, do you know a better way to bring in the image from the JSON??

Comment: I get this error for the second line above: Cannot convert value of type 'TableViewController.JSONstandard' (aka 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>') to expected argument type 'String'